# Thread re-runs the run() method

Tags: java, multithreading, tortoisesvn

I am learning about MultiThreading concepts. I just worked on a simple POC and found a little weird behaviour. Kindly help me

Goal :- To run 2 threads, one is "Tortoise" and other is "Hare". Making the Hare to sleep for 2 secs and allowing only tortoise to complete the thread before Hare.

My Runnable Class

```
package com.learn;

public class ThreadLearn implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        boolean flag = false;
        System.out.println("Running : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Hare")){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Flag before Setting : " +flag);
        if(!flag){
        System.out.println("Winner  : " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
        flag = true;
        System.out.println("Flag after Setting : " +flag);
        }


    }

}
```

and My main method class

```
package com.learn;

public class ThreadExecutor {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ThreadLearn l1 = new ThreadLearn();
        ThreadLearn l2 = new ThreadLearn();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(l1,"Tortoise");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(l2,"Hare");
        System.out.println("Thread STATE : " +Thread.currentThread().getState());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        System.out.println("END STATE : " +t1.getState());
    }

}
```

This is the output I got

---

```
Thread STATE : RUNNABLE
END STATE : RUNNABLE
Running : Tortoise
Running : Hare
Flag before Setting : false
Winner  : Tortoise
Flag after Setting : true
Flag before Setting : false
Winner  : Hare
Flag after Setting : true
```

If you see the output, I have set the "flag" as false in the run(), after making the hare therad  to sleep for 2 secs, Tortoise thread runs and sets the flag value as "true", so when the hare comes after 2 secs, my expectation was flag will be true and Winner sysout will not be printed at all. but the flag is again set as "false' and running the Winner sysout for Hare also. :( Please help me what is happening here.

Comment: `flag` is a local variable.

Comment: There are two instance of ThreadLearn, each of which has a run method containing a local variable 'flag'. Setting the value of the variable 'flag' in one location (eg in Tortoise) does not affect the other (Hare).

Answer (score 1):

each thread has own "flag" because you created 2 instances of ThreadLearn. both flags are independent. if you need to share 'flag' => you have to move 'flag' declaration from method to class body and mark it as static and volatile

Comment: Actually, the flags are not independent because there are 2 instances. Even with a single instance, there would be two independant flags. The field doesn't need to be static if a single instance is used.